# Touch ID Eror: com.apple.LocalAuthentication Code=-1004 , User interaction is required

Tags: ios, touch-id

I ran a Touch ID sample Code, and I changed the Bundle ID, the last builded App was OK, but the previous one with different Bundle ID was failed with error:

Touch ID Error:

> Error Domain=com.apple.LocalAuthentication Code=-1004 "User
>   interaction is required." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=User
>   interaction is required.}

Does anyone has the same problem? Same code with different Bundle ID, only the last builded one was OK .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS 8 Touch ID error "User interaction is required."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25919482/ios-8-touch-id-error-user-interaction-is-required)

Comment: I have tried ,thank you.

Comment: I am facing the same issue , if you get any solution let me know please.